# javascript recursion within an exports function: not a function

Tags: javascript, recursion

perennial newbie question: how do i fix this "not a function" error:

```
exports.height = (input) => {
    function height(node, height) {
        if (node.left) {
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
            **height(node.left, height+1); // <-- Says "Not a function"**
        }
    }

    var maxHeight = 0;
    height( input, 0 ); // <--- This works fine.

    return maxHeight;
}
```

says, TypeError: height is not a function

```
  at height (BinarySearchTree.js:53:5)
```

Thanks!
Nilesh

Comment: just change that to exports.height ,it should work

Comment: You named your parameter the same as the function. Did you try debugging with `console.log(height)`?

Comment: @Geeky: `exports.height` is referencing a different function. There are too many things named `height` in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you've shadowed the function variable named `height` with an argument of the same name:

```
function height(node, height) {
```

Because JavaScript functions are first-class citizens, in the context of the `height` function body, there is now a local variable named `height` which is not the same as the function.

Consider changing the name of one of them, like so:

```
function height(node, h) {
    if (node.left) {
        if (h > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = h;
        }
        height(node.left, h+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally **shadowed** your `height` variable

```
function height(node, height) {
    if (node.left) {
        if (height > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = height;
        }
        height(node.left, height+1);
    }
}

var maxHeight = 0;
height( input, 0 ); // 0 is obviously not a function ^_^
```

Try renaming the `height` parameter to something like `h`

```
function height(node, h) {
    if (node.left) {
        if (h > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = h;
        }
        return height(node.left, h+1); // don't forget your return
    }
}

var maxHeight = 0;
height( input, 0 );
```

All that said, you might want to reconsider your function alltogether

```
function height (node) {
  if (node === undefined)
    return -1;
  else
    return Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)) + 1;
}
```